# Inserting data to a implicit many-to-many relationship in Prisma

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, many-to-many, prisma, unique-constraint

I am building a website similar to LinkedIn/indeed and am facing difficulties when trying to update a job row when a user applies to a job. I am using Nest.js, Postgres and Prisma as the ORM.

Here are the schemas for the User and Job models:

```
model Job {
  id                 String          @id @default(cuid())
  title              String
  description        String
  postedAt           DateTime        @default(now())
  location           Location
  experienceLevel    ExperienceLevel
  monthlySalary      Int
  currency           String
  requirements       Requirement[]
  activelyRecruiting Boolean         @default(true)
  companyId          String
  company            Company         @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  applicants         User[]
}

model User {
  id            String       @id @default(cuid())
  username      String
  password      String
  email         String       @unique
  github        String?
  linkedin      String?
  website       String?
  resume        String?
  experiences   Experience[]
  skills        Skill[]
  education     Education[]
  appliedToJobs Job[]
  createdAt     DateTime     @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime     @updatedAt
}
```

I am using an implicit many-to-many relationship since I don't need to store metadata about the relationship. Here is the code I am writing to add a user to the Postgres database:

```
async applyToJob(id: string, accessor: Payload) {
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: accessor.id } });
        const job = await this.prisma.job.update({ where: { id }, data: { applicants: { create: [user] } } });
        return job;
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
async applyToJob(id: string, accessor: Payload) {
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: accessor.id } });
        const job = await this.prisma.job.update({ where: { id }, data: { applicants: { create: user } } });
        return job;
    }
```

Whenever I try adding a user to an applicant list which should then be able to update the appliedToJobs field in the user row, I get the following error:

```
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `this.prisma.job.update()` invocation in

  33
  34 async applyToJob(id: string, accessor: Payload) {
  35     const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: accessor.id } });
→ 36     const job = await this.prisma.job.update(
Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`id`)
    at Hr.handleRequestError (C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6999)
    at Hr.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6388)
    at Hr.request (C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6108)
    at l (C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\node_modules\.pnpm\@prisma+client@5.1.1_prisma@5.1.1\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:126:10298)
    at JobService.applyToJob (C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\src\job\job.service.ts:36:21)
    at C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\node_modules\.pnpm\@nestjs+core@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.8.1\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at C:\Users\Muham\Documents\dev-jobs\api\node_modules\.pnpm\@nestjs+core@10.0.0_@nestjs+common@10.0.0_@nestjs+platform-express@10.0.0_reflect-metadata@0.1.13_rxjs@7.8.1\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

I tried looking for solutions online, but most said that there must be a colliding field with the same ID, which is practically impossible since the id is randomly generated by Postgres. If someone could please tell me how to push a user to the applicants field in a row such that previous applicants remain in the list, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is attempting to create a new user in the user table instead of associating the existing user as an applicant on the job. It should be something like

```
async applyToJob(id: string, accessor: Payload) {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: accessor.id }});
    const job = await this.prisma.job.update({ where: { id }, data: { applicants: { connect: { id: user.id}}}});
    return job;
}
```

Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#connect-a-single-record